# Jetty has been embedded in maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty

when I use maven in my project, I dont install Jetty so is Jetty embedded in maven? how about others like Tomcat or glassfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven itself does not embed Jetty.

There is this Maven plugin called: `jetty-maven-plugin` which embeds jetty for fast development lifecycle.

There is also a Tomcat Maven Plugin... you guessed it... it embeds tomcat... if you use the tomcat:run goal that is... it also has goals that will deploy to your own install of tomcat though so it does not limit itself to embedding.

I think there is a Glassfish Maven Plugin that does not embed glassfish but does provide goals to use an existing installation.

There is also the cargo maven plugin which can provision some containers and run application on those containers

Comment: in which directory jetty-maven-plugin downloads the jetty?

Comment: the dependencies are downloaded by default into ~/.m2/repository/

Answer (score 1):

Maven basically is a build tool, managing libraries and dependencies in a project. Jetty, Tomcat and Glassfish are Servlet Containers, that means Web Servers, that interact with Servlets (and Glassfish is even more, it's a full-featured Application Server).

That said, Maven does also download required libraries for you. I suppose Jetty is in your case among those libraries, so Maven "installs" it for you and even starts the Server when you run the project. More Info here for example: 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin

Tomcat and Glassfish would have to be installed manually as far as i know.